# Discord v14 send message with Typescript

Tags: typescript, discord

I'm using discord14 and typescript.
I have a weird behaviour, sometimes the bot send a message, and sometime I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
at DiscordService.discordTest (/discord.service.ts:55:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at DiscordController.discordTest (/discord/discord.controller.ts:23:16)
```

My code is simple

```js
async discordTest() {
        // Creating a new client:
        const client = new Client({
            intents: [
                GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,                
                GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
            ]
        });


        const token = 'xxx'
        const AuthenticationToken = token;

        const logged = await client.login(AuthenticationToken);        
        console.log(logged);
        const channelId = 'yyy'        
        const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(channelId) as TextChannel;                
        

        console.log(channel)
        channel.send('test')


    }
```

I enabled the "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" checkbox in my application panel, and for now, the bot is Admin as well. I'm going to redefine the roles later

the call `client.channels.cache` return me as `undefined` sometimes.

***UPDATE***
using `const c = await client.channels.fetch(channelId) as TextChannel;`

I don't have any problem. So what is the different between cache and fetch? I can read cache in Discord documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache uses data from previous requests, fetch always sends calls for latest data. Using cache is purely for performance reasons (and sometimes so that your requests do not get blocked because you are sending way too many of them). This means that if you want to make your life easier you can always use fetch.

Here is a guide for editing cache behavior: https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/cache-customization.html#limiting-caches

Comment: thanks for your comment, it's weird, because if the first call success, the second call gets an error. In that moment the cache should be popolated

Comment: @monkeyUser This is only assumption, but it might happen, that first call goes because it has access to the entire data of request, but the second one does not, because data you are asking for did not make it to cache, because in `client.channels` there were too many of them, so only last x got cached. I doubt that this would be the behavior, but it's the only logical conclusion I can get to.